# PHP Detecting if source image url link leads to a "broken" image?

Tags: php, gd

Suppose you have a thumbnail generator script that accepts source images in the form of a URL. Is there a way to detect if the source URL is "broken" - whether nonexistent or leads to an non-image file?

---

Just brute force using `getimagesize()` or another PHP GD function is not a solution, since spoofed stray URL's that might not be images at all (`http://example.com/malicious.exe` or the same file, but renamed as `http://example.com/malicious.jpg`) could be input - such cases could easily be detected by PHP before having to invoke GD. I'm looking for GD pre-sanitizing before having GD try its battalion at parsing the file.

---

as a first step, the following regular expression checks if the URL is an image extension: 
`preg_match('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)@', $txt,$url);`

Comment: what's wrong with malicious.exe renamed to malicious.jpg? Tip: there is nothing wrong. in the context of thumbnails creation it's as dangerous as a plain text file.

Comment: `getimagesize()` is neither "brute force" nor a GD function. Itis exactly what you are looking for judging by what you are saying in the second paragraph.

Comment: How would you handle *changing* references? The URL might be a valid image when you create the thumb, but then might be changed later on.

Answer (score 11):

use `file_exists` function in php, you can check urls with it.

See documentation below, shows how to check img... exactly what you need

FILE EXISTS - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#93572

URL EXISTS - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#85246

---

Here is [alternative code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#84918) for checking the url. If you will test in browser replace `\n` with `<br/>`

```
<?php

$urls = array('http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png', 'http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2_not_exists.png');

foreach($urls as $url){
   echo "$url - ";
   echo url_exists($url) ? "Exists" : 'Not Exists';
   echo "\n\n";
}


function url_exists($url) {
    $hdrs = @get_headers($url);

    echo @$hdrs[1]."\n";

    return is_array($hdrs) ? preg_match('/^HTTP\\/\\d+\\.\\d+\\s+2\\d\\d\\s+.*$/',$hdrs[0]) : false;
}
?>
```

Output is as follows

```
http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png - Content-Type: image/png
Exists

http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2_not_exists.png - Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Not Exists
```

Comment: I use this all the time for detecting includes in my home-brew MVC setup. Works great and you can easily point to a default not-found image if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: 1) `file_exists` can only check for local files (?) 2) also.. url_exists looks like it is just invoking `curl_exec` -- does `curl_exec` return false if the $url is "broken" or (more specifically) is the wrong header type?

Comment: @ina see modification to my comment. I added url_exists method and example. Hope this helps you.

Comment: get_headers would be loing, use CURL with Multi Init

Answer (score 7):

I have used the following to detect attributes for remote images

```
$src='http://example.com/image.jpg';
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = @getimagesize($src);
```

example (checking stackoverflows "Careers 2.0" image)

```
$src='http://sstatic.net/ads/img/careers2-ad-header-so.png';
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = @getimagesize($src);

echo '<pre>';
echo $width.'<br>';
echo $height.'<br>';
echo $type.'<br>';
echo $attr.'<br>';
echo '</pre>';
```

If $height, $width etc is null the image is obvious not an image or the file does not exists. Using cURL is overkill and slower (even with CURLOPT_HEADER)

Answer (score 4):

The only really reliable way is to request the image using [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents), and finding out its image type using [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/getimagesize).

Only if `getimagesize()` returns a valid file type, can you rely that it is in fact a valid image.

This is quite resource heavy, though.

You could consider not doing any server-side checks at all, and adding an `onerror` JavaScript event to the finished image resource:

```
<img src="..." onerror="this.style.display = 'none'">
```

Comment: what if the file is not an image, i.e, renamed text file or other file?

Comment: it's all in vain. he's refused to understand

Comment: @ina in that case, `getimagesize` will fail and you will know it is not an image.

Comment: you're assuming too much of the php gd installation. on the current server, it will try to parse the file regardless, even if it's an .exe file or something - this is extra parsing in invoking gd when you can first check headers or extension to weed out such strays.

Comment: also, why use `file_get_contents()` when `curl()` has caching built in?

Comment: @ina you have no idea what you are talking about. `getimagesize()` has nothing to do with GD. It checks the *file format headers* (i.e. the first few bytes of the file) which is as good as a GD check, but without the overhead. It is the only waterproof and performance conscious way to parse an image file, take it or leave it. Regarding `curl` - of course you can use that instead of file_get_contents(), but I don't really see the point, especially about caching. What good is caching when you are trying to validate a resource?

Answer (score 2):

```
try for local files

<?php 
if(file_exists($filename))
{
//do what you want
}
else
{
//give error that file does not exists
}
?>
```

for external domains

```
$headers = @get_headers($url);
if (preg_match("|200|", $headers[0])) {
// file exists
} else {
// file doesn't exist
}
```

Also you can use curl request for the same.

Comment: this only works for local files - what if it's pointing to an external domain `http://anotherdomain.com/image.jpg`

Comment: @ina, i forgot to add below code.Thanks for pointing the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Fast Solution for broken or not found images link** 
i suggest you that don't use getimagesize() because it will 1st download image then it will check images size+if this will not image then it will throw exception so use below code

```
if(checkRemoteFile($imgurl))
{
//found url, its mean
echo "this is image";
}

function checkRemoteFile($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // don't download content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if(curl_exec($ch)!==FALSE)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note:**
this current code help you to identify broken or not found url image this will not help you to identify image type or headers

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) (it should be 200) and the [Content-type header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) (image/png etc.) of the HTTP response before you put the actual image through the generator.

If these two preconditions are ok, after retrieving the image you can call [`getimagesize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) on it and see if it breaks, what MIME type it returns etc.

Comment: is there a way to check for files that fake image content headers?

Comment: I don't think you can, without retrieving it. See my update :).

Answer (score 0):

did you try file_get_contents() method?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: this will create unnecessary data transfered for checking if file exists. better just to get a header, less work for server.

Comment: @Alex: Given the OP's determination to detect faked MIME headers, there is no way *without* file_get_contents. +1 to even out the score

Answer (score 0):

### [onerror Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp)

Execute a JavaScript if an error occurs when loading an image:

The onerror event is triggered if an error occurs while loading an external file (e.g. a document or an image).

**Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="image.gif" onerror="myFunction()">

<p>A function is triggered if an error occurs when loading the image. The function shows an alert box with a text.
In this example we refer to an image that does not exist, therefore the onerror event occurs.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert('The image could not be loaded.');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not detecting broken links, might be useful for someone else...

onerror=""

```
<img src="PATH" onerror="this.src='NEW PATH'" />
```