# Detecting whether an image is corrupted or broken

Tags: php, javascript, python, image

I need to programmatically check whether the image that the user has selected as his wallpaper on my app is broken or corrupted....... 
basically I provide user with the option to choose his own image as wallpaper. Now when the images loads, I just want to keep a check on whether it is somehow corrupt or not.......

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Comment: solutiion is here  
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568247/is-there-any-way-to-have-php-detect-a-corrupted-image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If instead you are looking for a PHP solution instead of a javascript solution (which the potential duplicates do not provide), you can use GD's [getimagesize()](http://php.net/getimagesize) in PHP and see what it returns. It will return false and throw an error when the provided image format is not valid.

Comment: image is corrupted but image size still comes.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a PHP CLI script you can run on a directory full of images and it will log which files are corrupted based on an `imagecreatefrom***()` test. It can just log the bad files or take action and delete them.

https://github.com/e-ht/literate-happiness

You can also plug it in to a database to take action on image paths that you may have stored.

Here is the meat of the function it uses:

```
$loopdir = new DirectoryIterator($dir_to_scan);
foreach($loopdir as $fileinfo) {
    if(!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $file = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        $file_path = $dir_to_scan . '/' . $file;
        $mime_type = mime_content_type($file_path);
        switch($mime_type) {
            case "image/jpg":
            case "image/jpeg":
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
                break;
            case "image/png":
                $im = imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
                break;
            case "image/gif":
                $im = imagecreatefromgif($file_path);
                break;
        }
        if($im) {
            $good_count++;
        }
        elseif(!$im) {
            $bad_count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. In some cases, `getimagesize` threw errors that I couldn't catch, but this worked in all cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work for me.

```
<?php
  $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if ($ext === 'jpg') {
    $ext = 'jpeg';
  }
  $function = 'imagecreatefrom' . $ext;
  if (function_exists($function) && @$function($image_file) === FALSE) {
    echo 'bad img file: ' . $image_file . ' ' . $function;
  }
?>
```

Comment: You have a typo at ```echo 'bad img file: ' . $image_file . ' ' . $function);```

Comment: *Use this instead: * `$function = 'imagecreatefrom' . strtolower($ext);`